# iTerm2 trigger on bell

Tags: iterm2

I'd like to trigger an action whenever I receive a bell character.

Currently I have a trigger with `\a` as the regular expression and "bounce dock icon" as the action. When I `echo \a` I can see the visual bell notification but the trigger does not bounce the dock icon. What am I doing wrong?

[image: iterm2 preferences]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bouncing the Dock Icon only works if the application is not currently the active app.

Try this in your shell:

```
sleep 2 ; echo ^G # Ctrl-v + Ctrl-g
```

After you press return on the line, switch to another application within 2 seconds... The iTerm dock icon will bounce to notify you that iTerm received a BEL and needs your attention.

[image]